# Understanding Constraints using Xcode and Manually Coding

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I just read few information about how to manipulates constraints number programatically, but I think I need to see it visually using Xcode. So I decided to put a UIView like this and see what's going on with Constraints :

[image]

automatically it will create 4 constraints :

[image]

after modifying the number, I got what's the meaning of all this. there we have 2 vertical space and 2 horizontal space. but let's focus on vertical first...

one of vertical space measured from top of the screen (superview, I guess), I give this number 30. and other vertical space measured from the bottom, I give -50.

now, when it turns into code, I really don't understand how to give this 2 numbers. as far as I know, here's how to set constraint with code :

```
NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:_screenView
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:_container
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                   multiplier:20
                                   constant:200];
[_screenView addConstraint: myConstraint];
```

let's assume `_screenView` is a superview and `_container` is UIView placed on top of it. I have 3 questions :

1. How to set both vertical space (30 and -50) manually with code? because from storyboard I don't see any different name or ID of vertical space. they both have same name. do I have to create 2 `NSLayoutConstraint` ?
2. Then how to add it into _screenView? do I have to create this : `[_screenView addConstraint: myConstraint];` twice?
3. what `multiplier` used for? because I don't see that option in storyboard.

thank you very much.

Comment: First stop and consider moving to Xcode 5 now. It's quite different how you work with constraints and you might as well spend your time learning it there.

Comment: I'm downloading Xcode 5 right now ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's important to think of this formula from Apple's Auto Layout Guide when working with constraints:

```
y = m*x + b, where:

y and x are attributes of views.

m and b are floating point values.
```

You can think the constraint for the top of _container like this:

```
_containter.top = m*_screenView.top + b
```

When you are creating a constraint using `NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:...` the multiplier argument is "m" and constant is "b" in this formula. To create a constraint that keeps the top of _container 30 points below the top of _screenView you would do this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:_container
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:_screenView
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                   multiplier:1.0
                                   constant:30.0];
```

The bottom constraint would be:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint =[NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:_container
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:_screenView
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                   multiplier:1.0
                                   constant:-50.0];
```

Also keep in mind that in the UIKit coordinate system X values go up from left to right and Y values go up from top to bottom. In other words, 0,0 is at the top-left of screen and the values go up from there.

If you want to create the four contraints you show above you will have to create them all individually. You could also use the `constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:` method of NSLayoutConstraint to make multiple at once. I find it more clear to write them out the way I did above.

Comment: you're a really helpful, Alex... I really appreciate it! thanks a lot! I love you, man!!

Comment: but if you have 2 NSLayoutConstraint with same name : myConstraint, how to add it into component? is it enough by having this line : [_screenView addConstraint: myConstraint];

Comment: or should I change into different names? and have this lines : [_screenView addConstraint: myConstraint1]; and [_screenView addConstraint: myConstraint2];

Comment: Correct, if you want to assign both to variables you will have to use different variable names. I made a mistake using the same variable name twice in my example. However, I generally skip this step and do `[_someView addconstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraint...]]`. I only assign the constraint to an instance variable if I want to be able to access it later to change my layout (during an orientation change or other UI animation).

Comment: Before I forget to mention it.... Keep in mind that the only property of a constraint you can change after creation is the constant value. If you want to update or animate a constraint this is your only option. It's worth keeping this in mind when designing your constraints. Also, become familiar with the `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:` UIView method. When you create constraints manually you will generally want to set this to NO for all of your view objects to avoid conflicts.