# UItableviewcell dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier removeFromSuperview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

This is probably a simple problem, but I haven't found the right solution yet, so I am hoping somebody can help.

I have a tableview from storyboard with a cell with three labels.
All labels are connected via `IBOutlet` and have correct constrains.

The issue is that I want to remove the second label based on data so the constraints are kept and the third label uses its lower constraints to move closer to the first label.

But when I run the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"GroupMaterialCell";

  GroupMaterialCell *cell = (GroupMaterialCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

  // get data and populate row
  if([self.materialitems count] >= indexPath.row) {

    Material *material = [self.materialitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.folder.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", NSLocalizedString(@"Folder", nil), material.folder];cell.name.text = material.name;;
    cell.member.text = material.member_name;
    cell.date.text = [material getDate];
    cell.info.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", [material getType], [material getFilesize]];

    if([material.folder length] <= 0) {
        [cell.folder removeFromSuperview];
    }

  }

    return cell;
}
```

The code works perfect until I scroll down and it reuses the cells.
Then the second label is "gone" (removeFromSuperview) and therefore not visible.

Is there a quick way to do this without creating the label in code (with constrainst) and add / remove it?

Hope it all makes sense, otherwise ask.

**UPDATE**

The solution is to hide to label and set the priorities on the constraints.

Create IBOutlet of the constraints you want to switch

Edit code with following.

```
if([material.folder length] <= 0) {
        [cell.folder setHidden:YES];
        cell.memberToFolder.priority = 500;
        cell.memberToName.priority = 900;
    } else {
        [cell.folder setHidden:NO];
        cell.memberToFolder.priority = 900;
        cell.memberToName.priority = 500;

    }
```

Comment: Obviously dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier reuses a cell our may have changed the structure previously. An option would be hiding the label and changing the constraints values in this method as needed

Comment: Sounds fair, but how do i Programmably set the new constraint?

Comment: You can connect the constraint via IBOutlet the same way you do it with the label

Comment: Ok a added the two constraints as IBOutlet and then used this code: `if([material.folder length] <= 0)[cell.group setHidden:YES];
            cell.nameToGroup.priority = 750;
            cell.nameToDate.priority = 1000;
            
        } else {
            
            [cell.group setHidden:NO];
            cell.nameToGroup.priority = 1000;
            cell.nameToDate.priority = 750;}` but then i get:  You passed priority 1000 and the existing priority was 1000 ??

Comment: Figured it out.. priority 1000, 750 and 250 are some kind of milestones and therefore cant be used like this. After i changed it to 900 and 500 everything seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Do not remove any thing from cell just handle it with it's visibility

```
      if([material.folder length] <= 0) {
              //set frame if required
                [cell.folder setHidden:true];
            } else {
             //set frame if required
               [cell.folder setHidden:false];
       }
```

Comment: if i use setHidden it doesnt use the right constraint :-(

Comment: RemoveFromSuperView is not a good idea. just set/update constraint value according to your need in that if & else clause.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884470/understanding-constraints-using-xcode-and-manually-coding

Comment: http://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/09/24/ios-animating-autolayout-constraints/